# How can I encode string data (convert to bytes) in Python 3.7

Tags: python, string

i have a problem.

i get data like:

```
hex_num='0EE6'
data_decode=str(codecs.decode(hex_num, 'hex'))[(0):(80)]
print(data_decode)
>>>b'\x0e\xe6'
```

And i want encode this like:

```
data_enc=str(codecs.encode(data_decode, 'hex'))[(2):(6)]
print(str(int(data_enc,16)))
>>>TypeError: encoding with 'hex' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')
```

If i wrote this:

```
data_enc=str(codecs.encode(b'\x0e\xe6', 'hex'))[(2):(6)]
print(str(int(data_enc,16)))
>>>3814
```

It will retrun number what i want (3814)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the quotation marks like this: `data = b'\x0e\xe6'`

The [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) states:

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes.

When `b` is within a string, it will not behave like a string literal prefix, so you have to remove the quotations for the literal to work, and convert the text to bytes directly.

Corrected code:

```
import codecs
data = b'\x0e\xe6'
data_enc=str(codecs.encode(data, 'hex'))[(2):(6)]
print(str(int(data_enc,16)))
```

Output:

```
3814
```

Comment: It would be more beneficial to OP if you could explain the reason of that as well

Comment: Please don't edit the question, that can make it difficult for future users. If you want to ask another question, post a new question, don't edit the current one!

Answer (score 0):

To change from a hex string to binary data, then using `binascii.unhexlify` is a convenient method. e.g.:

```py
>>> hex_num='0EE6'
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify(hex_num)
b'\x0e\xe6'
```

Then to convert the binary data to an integer, using `int.from_bytes` allows you control over the endianness of the data and if it signed. e.g:

```py
>>> bytes_data = b'\x0e\xe6'
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes_data, byteorder='little', signed=False)
58894
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes_data, byteorder='big', signed=False)
3814
```